# Prove: $|\mathbf{I}+\mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}^{\mathrm{T}}|=1+\mathbf{a}^{\mathrm{T}}\mathbf{b}$

Tags: matrices, determinant

This is the formula (C.15) in the "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning" appendix.
$$|\mathbf{I}+\mathbf{a}\mathbf{b}^{\mathrm{T}}|=1+\mathbf{a}^{\mathrm{T}}\mathbf{b}$$
$\mathbf{I}\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ is identity matrix.
$\mathbf{a,b\in\mathbb{R}^N}$ is column vector.
$|\cdot|$ is determinant.
($N\ge 2$)
How can I prove the formula?

Comment: You might need some conditions on $N$ because take $N = 1$, $a = -2, b = 2$. Then $|I + ab^T| = |1 + (-2)\cdot 2| = 3 \neq 1 + (-2)\cdot 2 = -3$.

Comment: Fixed. Thank you.

Comment: @EpsilonAway Watch out, a "determinant bar" is not an "absolute value bar"!

Comment: @MathDrifter Ah, true. So my counter-example doesn't really work.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma

Answer (score 2):

Since $a$ and $b$ are vectors, $ab^{T}$ is an $N\times N$ matrix of rank $1$, and so $N-1$ of its eigenvalues are $0$.  Since the trace of a matrix is the sum of the eigenvalues, that means the non-zero eigenvalue must be $\operatorname{tr}(ab^T)=\operatorname{tr}(b^Ta)=b^Ta$ where the latter, which is a $1\times 1$ matrix, is viewed as a scalar.  Note that we have used the cyclic shift property of trace, that $\operatorname{tr}(AB)=\operatorname{tr}(BA)$ for any matrices such that the products exist and are square.

If you have a matrix $M$, then the eigenvectors of $M+\lambda I$ are the same as the eigenvectors of $M$, but the eigenvalues all increase by $\lambda$.  Since the eigenvalues of $ab^T$ are $b^Ta$ with multiplicity $1$ and $0$ with multiplicity $N-1$, the eigenvalues of $I+ab^T$ will be $1+b^Ta$ with multiplicity $1$ and $1$ with multiplicity $N-1$.

Finally, we use the fact that the determinant of a matrix is the product of the eigenvalues to get $\det(I+ab^T)=(1+b^Ta)(1)^{N-1}=1+b^Ta=1+a^Tb$.